# Android Get Id of Value in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm using xml array with value and its Id.I want to get Id of value after user selects it.Kindly tell me how can I get that?

```
<string-array name="medicine">
    <item id="21058">ALPHA LIPOIC ACID</item>
    <item id="19699">B 50 VITAMIN</item>
    <item id="19470">B100 ULTRA  50S</item>
</string-array>

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.medicine));
    AutoCompleteTextView actv= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    actv.setOnClickListener(this);
    actv.setThreshold(1);
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found its answer myself. I made a model for `ArrayList`, I assign that `ArrayList` to the `AutoCompleteTextView Adapter` and then, the `OnClick` event of the `AutoCompleteTextView` gives me the exact id and value.

Comment: Please, post your answer. what is model ? your answer is tricky to understand